# how to find Macro standard object in production environment?

Tags: deployment

I try to deploy my sandbox to production environment. but I got an error :

```
Macro   customObject 0 0 Invalid fullName, must end in a custom suffix ( for ex. __c )
```

I realize that my sandbox have standard object name Macro while my production environment not.

How can I solve this problem ?
thanks !!!

Comment: What edition is your production instance?